# How to set cookie and session in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have to make a login page which will contain username and password. When the user logs in a cookie will be created for that session. This cookie will contain userid and the time he logs in. Now he/she is surfing pages after login. But suppose user do not execute any action on certain page and after 2 mins he/she starts using that page then that session must expires because we have set in session that user will be automatically logged out if he/she do not perform any action on any page for 2 mins.

Comment: isn't there anything in google search?

Comment: `this cookie will contain userid and the time he logs in` that sounds like a terrible idea. Why not just store a session ID? ... anyhow, your Google query is probably  `cakephp session expiry`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `Session.timeout` setting in config/core.php. The value depends on the `Security.level` setting: if it's set to 'high' the value is multiplied by 10 and if it's set to 'medium' it's multiplied by 100, so put in 12 or 1.2 respectively for 120 seconds (although I'm not 100% sure it accepts other than whole numbers).

This will of course not invalidate other than session cookies, but creating your own cookies for login info is probably a bad idea anyway.